# Monad Morphisms applicability questiion

Tags: haskell, monads

I am trying to do something, and I think Monad Morphisms are the answer, but I am unsure how to correctly apply them here. Briefly, I have the following setup:

```
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Writer

data F = F Bool Bool

instance Monoid F where
    mempty =  F True False
    (F s0 c0) `mappend` (F s1 c1) = F (s0 && s1)
                                    (c0 || c1 || not (s0 || s1))
type S = Writer F
type SInt = S Int
```

Above I define datatype F with two boolean flags, which state I track using Writer monad. For example, I will use them in the function foo:

```
foo :: SInt -> SInt -> SInt
foo = liftM2 (+)
```

Now, I would like in certain situations, to implement different flags handling logic and use it with `foo` without changing `foo`'s type signature. In particular, I would like to change Monoid definition above to this:

```
instance Monoid F where
    mempty =  F True False
    (F s0 c0) `mappend` (F s1 c1) = F (s0 && s1) (c0 || c1)
```

Is this something I could do with the help of [Monad Morphisms](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html)? How?

Comment: Perhaps simply give `foo` a more general type, e.g. `Monoid w => Writer w Int -> Writer w Int -> Writer w Int` - in this case you can instantiate `foo` with different monoids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you actually want is to reuse `foo`, you can just make it polymorphic...

```
foo :: (Monoid b) => Writer b Int -> Writer b Int -> Writer b Int
```

... and give your instances to two different types (I will write them as `newtypes` around tuples, but you can do it differently if you want):

```
newtype F = F { unF :: (Bool, Bool) }
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Monoid F where -- etc.

newtype G = G { unG :: (Bool, Bool) }
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Monoid G where -- etc.
```

As for using a monad morphism, you can certainly write a function such as...

```
bar :: Writer F a -> Writer G a
bar = writer . fmap (G . unF) . runWriter
```

... which effectively just swaps the `Monoid` instance, as you originally wanted to. However, you won't be able to use the *mmorph* machinery, as it isn't actually a monad morphism. Quoting [`Control.Monad.Morph`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html):

```
-- A monad morphism is a natural transformation:

 morph :: forall a . m a -> n a

-- ... that obeys the following two laws:

 morph (m >>= f)  = morph m >>= morph . f
 morph (return x) = return x
```

The obvious implementation of `bar` violates the first of these laws, as the `mappend`s implicit in `m >>= f` and `morph m >>= morph . f` can give different results even if the underlying pairs of booleans are the same.

Comment: @krokodil The RHS type in the first law is `n a` (the function on the right of `(>>=)` is `f` *then* `morph`), and the comparison uses the full `n a` monadic value. (By the way: it is worth emphasising that, as long as you don't plan to use `bar` with `hoist`, `embed` and the other tools in `Control.Monad.Morph`, you don't need to worry it not being a monad morphism.)